# Which status code return when user is authenticated but not authorizated?

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

On the system exists two types of user: teachers and students.

Rule:

- Only teachers can create projects by accessing `/new/project`. When this occurs, the status code of response is `200`.

Problem:

In a REST scenerios, if students try to access the `/new/project` which status code must be returned in:

- Ajax requests
- "Normal" requests

Students must be redirects (302)?

Students must see a not found page (404) as [github](https://github.com/new) does?

What about 403 status?

Comment: If the user does not have the permission to access the resource, then 403 is the appropriate HTTP response code.

Comment: `401 Unauthorized` is used when someone tries to login and the login fails or tries to access a protected resource and hasn't authenticated yet. `403 Forbidden` is used when someone is authorized, but has insufficient privileges to access the requested resource. You can see a list of status codes and their definition on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).